# Encoding in linq/entity framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, character-encoding

I'm working on a legacy where some fields uses special encodings. Is it somehow possible to set an decode the fields in the linq instead of doing as I'm doing now:

```
XisoEncoding enc = new XisoEncoding()

var q = from b in ent.Basket
            where b.ID == 22038
            select b;

Basket basket = query.First();
basket.STOMAN_MESSAGE = enc.DecodeString(basket.STOMAN_MESSAGE);

.....
```

Comment: yes, the STOMAN_MESSAGE value is a database retrieved field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity classes are defined as partial classes. You could add a new property to the Basket class, for example `DecodedStomanMessage`, which returns the decoded message.

I would not modify the `STOMAN_MESSAGE` property itself, since this will mark the entity as modified, and you could end up sending the decoded version back to the database.